# In grails 3.3.9 Auto reload of grails inline plugin for controller and services not working although js file changes are reflecting

Tags: grails, groovy, gradle-plugin, grails-3.3.x

We have upgraded our project from grails 3.2.x to 3.3.9 then for any inline plugin auto reload of classes i.e services and controller not working  although js file changes are instantly reflecting

Have tried exploded=true but it still not working

Show following error while changing anything in class
Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventRestController Reason: Interfaces changed from [grails/artefact/Controller, grails/artefact/gsp/TagLibraryInvoker, grails/artefact/controller/RestResponder, org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait, grails/artefact/controller/RestResponder$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/gsp/TagLibraryInvoker$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/web/api/WebAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/Controller$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/web/api/ServletAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/RequestForwarder$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRedirector$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRenderer$Trait$FieldHelper] to [grails/artefact/Controller, grails/artefact/gsp/TagLibraryInvoker, grails/artefact/controller/RestResponder, grails/plugin/springsecurity/ControllerMixin, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail, org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/RestResponder$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/gsp/TagLibraryInvoker$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/web/api/WebAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/Controller$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/web/api/ServletAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/RequestForwarder$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRedirector$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRenderer$Trait$FieldHelper]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.